# Why does the charge distribution on the surface of a conducting sphere remain uniform even if there is a perturbation in the inner electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

In a conducting sphere, the net charge is evenly distributed at the surface because of repulsion while the inner electric field remains zero as charges cancel inside. Here is an example, where the net charge is the sum of the positive charges evenly distributed at the surface, which are what create the outer electric field:

[image]

However, even if the inner positive charge is moved, the outer surface charge distribution remains unchanged:
[image]

Why exactly does this happen? I assume it's because the perturbation in the inner electric field (which for an instant creates a net inner electric field) reaches the inner electrons before reaching the surface positive charges, and by the time the perturbation in the field would have reached the positive charges on the surface, there's already been a redistribution of charge inside. Is this correct?

Doesn't the surface distribution change at all, even if for an instant?

I'm looking for a more intuitive/visual explanation, like the idea above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know by Gauss Law, electric field inside a conductor is zero.Thus in what ever orientation the negative charge is induced in the inner surface of the conductor it creates no electric field through the conductor thus it cannot affect the orientation of the positive charge on the outer surface. This is because a charge can only be moved or displaced by electric field so no inner charge can manipulate the charge distribution on the outer surface. See the image attached below,

[image]

Comment: So when there's a movement of charge inside the conductor, there's a momentary perturbation in the field, which causes ONLY the inner charges to move to counteract any changes and so the electric field inside always remains zero? Is this correct?

Comment: Yup, field inside any conductor is 0.[By inside I mean the solid part of the conductor and not the cavity].

Comment: There is no field passing through the conductor to interact with the outer surface charge.

Comment: So it's simply that the electric field of the inner positive charge on the diagram cancels the inner electric field of the surface charges and so there is no longer any interaction between the surface and the inside of the sphere?

Comment: No, it's a property of conductor(can be proved by Gauss law) that it doesn't allow any electric field to pass through it, it more or less acts like a shield.

Comment: There is nothing to do with the positive charge inside

Comment: Since it's a property of a conductor, apart from being proved by Gauss' law, could it be because of the equal number of positive and negative charges inside which interact before any surface interaction can occur?

Comment: Yes, you can explain it that way too..I think!

Comment: Also, is there a method to measure the cavity inside?

Comment: What exactly about cavity?

Comment: Given that it's a region where there is no electric field, is there a way to determine it's width using an equation related to the net charges?

Comment: Whatever the size of cavity be the result will always be same.....the negative charge density may vary on the inner surface...

Comment: So far I haven't seen any such equation...there may be something like that in higher studies.

Comment: the negative charge density ONLY on the inner surface?

Comment: Try out yourself, though there is no option to vary cavity size https://simphy.com/weblets/conductor-field-lines/

Comment: One last problem...is there no interaction between inner electrons and the outer net positive charges, since their electric fields are infinite?

Comment: Infinite?......

Comment: Yes, infinite. While a certain flux line may 'cancel' with the central positive charge, there are many other flux lines, since the electric field of an electron is radial

Comment: I have told you, for a charge to interact with another charge it's field lines must reach the other charge, and here the field lines of negative charge is blocked by the conductor itself thus they can't react to the surface of conductor for interacting.